# Kibana keep showing error unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have setup elastic search 8.2.3 and it runs and the status is green. I also setup the Kibana. When I run it from the console it keeps showing the info warning below however, I can log in to Kibana UI. Not sure why this error info is being displayed. Can you help?

[image]

[image]

**Kibana yml file config:**

[image]

**Kibana Console error:**

> [2022-09-22T09:49:10.777-07:00][INFO ][plugins.security.authentication] Authentication attempt failed: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/_security/_authenticate]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8"","ApiKey"]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/_security/_authenticate]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8"","ApiKey"]}},"status":401}

Answer (score 0):

Just as a test, change the "elasticsearch.hosts" for [http://elastic:elasticpassword@127.0.0.1:9200], then check the logs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you have aout enable

Example:

```
curl --location 'https://localhost:9200/' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic ZWxhc3RpYzpOWkdidWxyNzQ9YzJlanYqcnNqUQ=='
```